# C#: passing nullable variable to method that only accepts nonnull vars

Tags: c#, nullable

I have code that is similar to this:

```
public xyz (int? a)
{
  if (a.HasValue)
  { 
    // here DoSomething has parameters like DoSomething(int x)
    blah = DoSomething(a);
```

I am getting the error (cannot convert from int? to int).  Is there a way I can pass the variable 'a' to my function without having to do `DoSomething(int? x)`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `Value` property of the nullable variable:

```
public xyz (int? a) {
  if (a.HasValue) { 
    blah = DoSomething(a.Value);
    ...
```

The [`GetValueOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58x571cw.aspx) method might also be useful in some situations:

```
x = a.GetValueOrDefault(42);  // returns 42 for null
```

or

```
y = a.GetValueOrDefault(); // returns 0 for null
```

Answer (score 6):

You can cast the `int?` to an `int` or use `a.Value`:

```
if (a.HasValue)
{ 
  blah = DoSomething((int)a);

  // or without a cast as others noted:
  blah = DoSomething(a.Value);
}
```

If this is followed by an else that passes in a default value, you can handle that all in one line, too:

```
// using coalesce
blah = DoSomething(a?? 0 /* default value */);

// or using ternary
blah = DoSomething(a.HasValue? a.Value : 0 /* default value */);

// or (thanks @Guffa)
blah = DoSomething(a.GetValueOrDefault(/* optional default val */));
```

Comment: Casting is not ideal for getting the value, it's unclear if the intention was to make a conversion or not. The GetValueOrDefault method is clearer than both the coalesce operathr and the conditional operator.

Comment: @Guffa: highly subjective. For someone that knows the language, GetValueOrDefault is verbose and coalesce is as clear as it gets. Agree with the casting part though.

Comment: @Guffa: wasn't the coalesce operator introduced exactly for the use with nullable types?